# Sniffing USB traffic at the hardware level

Tags: usb, analysis, protocol

I've been looking to purchase a USB sniffer that will parse packets at the hardware level. I've used `usbsnoopy` and the like, but a filter driver solution is not my goal here.

Does anyone know of a hardware solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: +1, filter drivers can get quite nasty... especially with newer versions of Windows (assuming you're a Windows user)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the LeCroy protocol analyzer suite, most likely the Voyager M3i in particular. It can handle both USB 2.0 and 3.0 traffic and allows you to identify your packet structure patterns with custom configuration files.

[image: Voyager]

**[Product Page](http://www.lecroy.com/protocolanalyzer/protocoloverview.aspx?seriesid=164&capid=103&mid=511)**

Answer (score 2):

I've used the Beagle USB analyzer. I found the software to be very capable and updated often. It will show you a breakdown of all transactions on the bus, including the state of the electrical bus.

http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle_usb12/